# Proper way to ack/anchor Storm tuples

Tags: apache-storm

I have a bolt that works in small batches of tuples. I essentially have a `switch` statement that listens for either a stream from a previous bolt, or a `tick tuple`.  It looks something like this:

```
switch(component) {
    bolt1:
      do some work...
      anchors.add(tuple)
    tick:
      do some work...
      collector.emit(anchors, value)
      collector.ack(tuple)
      anchors.clear()
```

When I run this, Storm UI shows a very small number of tuples acked from this bolt.  Is this the correct way to anchor them or do I need to call `collector.ack(tuple)` within the bolt switch statement as well?  Even though Storm UI counts are weird, the topology is running without any of the tuples timing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not ack the tuples in the bolt1 case if you want to replay the pending anchors if the worker crashes. You never want to ack tuples more than once either.

It looks like you're acking the tick tuple and not the anchors in the tick case? You should ack the anchors as well, or the spout will be told they've failed once you hit the topology message timeout.

Comment: I see, thanks for the information!  Are you saying in addition to passing the anchors to the emit method, I also need to loop through the list of anchors and ack each one individually?  My understanding is that if the bolt after this one acks properly, there's no need to loop through and ack individually here.

Comment: Yes, you have to ack the anchors as well. I think taking a look at https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html would help illustrate how Storm works for you. Essentially Storm keeps track of a tree/graph of tuples for each tuple emitted by the spout. When your bolt emits a tuple, a new edge is created in the tuple graph rooted at the tuple originally emitted by the spout. All edges in the graph (e.g. your anchors) have to be acked, or the tuple emitted by the spout fails.

Comment: Got it, thanks!  I've bone over that link before but they don't mention looping through the list of multiple anchors.  I'll add that to my code and see what changes!